# Passing shell commands parameters securely with %x[] in Ruby

Tags: ruby, security, shell

Let's say I have in a Rails controller:

```
dir = params[:dir]
output = %x[ls #{dir}]
```

This is a HUGE security hole if somebody posts `dir="foo; rm -rf /"`

So I need to secure the parameter. I know I could do

```
system "ls", dir
```

But this method does not capture stdout !

So, how can I securely pass parameters to %x[] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `%x()` basically hands a string to the shell to be parsed so you'd have to escape everything that the shell could possibly interpret. So `%x` is pretty much out the window if you need to deal with anything that you haven't built yourself (and event then it is suspect).

One solution is to use [Open3.capture3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html#M001647):

```
out, err, status = Open3.capture3('/bin/ls', dir)
```

and then deal with the standard output (`out`) and standard error (`err`) returns as needed. There are a few other things in Open3 that might serve your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Ruby's safe levels?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html

For levels >= 2 it says "Can't change, make, or remove directories, or use chroot."

There also used to be a sandbox gem, but I'm not sure if that's still active. You also could have a look at the source of "Try Ruby!" there has to be some kind of sandboxing in there.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, however I'd prefer to find a simplest way. After all if system can do it, exec should be able to do it too :)